# How can I make ReportViewer display field dynamically?

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I have a ReportViewer with LocalReport in an Asp.Net webform that currently has four placeholders, each containing a different field.

**What I am looking to do is to change the placeholders from this:**

```
[Name]
[Address1]
[Address2]
[CityStateZip]
```

**To a more conditional display such as:**

```
[Name]
[Address1]
if(Address2 != null)[Address2] else [CityStateZip]
if(Address2 != null)[CityStateZip] else ""
```

**Is there a way I can do this in the rdlc?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,
you can do this with iif in RDLC expression.
try this

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Address2.Value), Fields!Address2.Value, Fields!CityStateZip.Value)
```